# Question related to print <<<

Tags: wordpress

Can any one explain me what does following statement means? I have found this statement in wordpress plugin "FLV EMBED". these statement are:

```
1.   print <<< JS

2. print <<< XML_HEAD
   $xml_head}
   <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
   xmlns:video="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.0">
   XML_HEAD;
```

Can I print these statements with `echo "";` ? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print` is also a language construct to output data to the screen, the only difference with `echo` is that echo accepts multiple parameters

`<<<` is used to output multiple lines

You can create exactly the same functionality using echo, including using `<<<`